# SQL Server Query and convert to Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I do have 4 tables:

```
Entity (EntityId (PK),Name), 
MultimediaEntity(IdMultimediaEntity (PK), EntityId (FK), FileId(FK), Principal),
File ( FileId(PK),Name),
BinaryFile(FileId, Binary,FileGuid)
```

and I need to retrieve, using Linq, the Binary of a certain file, but that file got to match the EntityId that I receive in my method public ActionResult GetEntityFileById(int? EntityId).

```
    select BinaryFile.Binary
    from File
    inner join BinaryFile on BinaryFile.FileId=File.FileId

    select MultimediaEntity.FileId
    from File
inner join Entity on Entity.EntityId=MultimediaEntity.EntityId
```

I know I will need 2 inner joins but how can I retrieve my desired result?

EDIT: need to do an inner join to retrieve my Binary property of my model, any help?

```
public ActionResult GetEntityFileById(int? EntityId) 
        {

            RecursosSearch getEntityById = (from e in db.Entity
                           join
                           t in db.EntityType on e.EntityId equals t.EntityId                          join 
                           m in db.MultimediaEntity on e.EntityId equals m.EntityId
                           where t.EntityTypeId == 2301 && e.PublishedOnInternet && e.EntityId==EntityId
                           orderby e.Name
                           select new RecursosSearch
                           {
                               Name = e.Name,
                               Biography=e.Biography,
                               Binary=(from m in db.MultimediaEntity
                                        join 
                                        e in db.Entity on e.EntityId equals m.EntityId
                                        join 
                                        f in db.File on m.FileId equals f.FileId

                           }).FirstOrDefault();
```

and this is my model:

```
 public class RecursosSearch
    {
        public int EntityId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Biography { get; set; }
        public byte[] Binary { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Post the Entity Model, not the View Model.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an EF model with Navigation Properties, and you just want the first file associated with the EntityId, then something like this:

```
var q = db.MultimediaEntity
          .Where(e => e.EntityId == EntityId)
          .Select( e => e.File.BinaryFile.Binary );


byte[] fileContents = q.FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
var q = from e in db.MultimediaEntity
        where e.EntityId == EntityId
        select e.File.BinaryFile.Binary;

byte[] fileContents = q.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: hmm guess not David Browne. It doesn't recognize e.File.BinaryFile.Binary;. Guess i will have to cross all the structure no?

Comment: It all depends on your EF model.  Add that to the question.

Comment: it's updated, need to retrieve my Binary property like that above